# Python: Giving Score for Each Word stored in a Variable after Looping

Tags: python, list, loops, twitter, lexicon

I have a case that I need to solve but I've been stuck with no solution for almost a week. 
here's the case. I have three variables:

```
candidates = ["you", "the", "best", "love", "fun", "feeling", "emotionally"]
seeds = ["happy", "love", "enjoy", "fun", "grace", "sad", "guilty"]
tweets = ["you look so happy", "I am in love with you", "hey you do the best at having fun okay", "i am emotionally sad right now", "feeling guilty"]
```

and what I want to do is I want to pair the word from variable "candidates" with words from "seeds", loop them together over the tweets and give score after loop to each word from variable "candidates".

so for example: 
for the first loop I pair:

```
you + happy
you + love
you + enjoy
you + fun
you + grace
you + sad
you + guilty
```

and loop them over the strings in variable "tweets" and give the score based on how many times these pair appear in sentences from variable tweets. so in this case the score I'll get for word "you" paired with all words from variable "seeds" are 3.

and continue with the second loop with pairs which are:

```
the + happy
the + love
the + fun
the + enjoy
the + grace
the + sad
the + guilty
```

and loop them over again to the strings in variable "tweets" and give the score based on how many times these pair appear in sentences from variable tweets. so in this case the score I'll get for word "you" paired with all words from variable "seeds" are 1.

I want my program to be able to automatically return score for each word from variable "candidates" paired with words from variable "seeds" and loop them together to the strings in variable "tweets".

```
#looping all pair candidates and seed to the tweets
for tweet in tweets:
    for candidate in candidates:
        for seed in seeds:
            if candidate in tweet and seed in tweet:
                if "happy" in tweet or "love" in tweet or "fun" in tweet:
                    print(candidate, seed, tweet)
                    count_happy += 1
                elif "sad" in tweet or "guilty" in tweet:
                    print(candidate, seed, tweet)
                    count_sad += 1
        count_a += 1
```

above is the script I created to do what I want to do but it doesn't work the way I want it to. so please does anyone know how to solve this problem of mine? it's been a week already and I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: Are you basically just counting the occurrences of words? Also, why do you pair up the candidates with the seeds if you're just counting them separately?

Comment: i want to count the occurences of each word from candidates that is paired with words from seeds. so basically the score will be how many times the word A paired with words from seeds are in the setences.

Comment: do you get what I mean?

Comment: so take example the first word "you". i want to pair it with all words from seeds and loop them over all sentences from tweets and give me the score for word "you" based on how many times word "you" and its pairs appear in all sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample script for what you want to do :
what is did is added each candidate element to dictionary with key as candidate name+ a string all seeds . When looping through seeds i just append this key's value with +=1

```
import codecs
import itertools
import threading
import csv


candidates = []
seeds = []
tweets = []
global lock

with codecs.open("d:\\untitled\\candidates.csv", encoding='utf8')  as candFile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(candFile, delimiter=',')
    for lines in candFile:
        if lines.rstrip() != "" :
            candidates.append(lines.rstrip())

with codecs.open("d:\\untitled\\seeds.csv",encoding='utf8')  as candFile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(candFile, delimiter=',')
    for lines in candFile:
        if lines.rstrip() != "" :
            seeds.append(lines.rstrip())

with codecs.open("d:\\untitled\\tweets.csv", encoding='utf8')  as candFile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(candFile, delimiter=',')
    for lines in candFile:
        if lines.rstrip() != "" :
            tweets.append(lines.rstrip())


counts = {}


def findMatch(listToWorkWith,tweet):
    for CS in listToWorkWith:
        if (CS[0] in tweet) and (CS[1] in tweet):
            try:
                counts[CS[0] + "+ All Seeds"] += 1
            except:
                counts[CS[0] + "+ All Seeds"] = 1


listOFAugrs = list(itertools.product(candidates, seeds))
lock = threading.Lock()
threads = [threading.Thread(target=findMatch, args=(listOFAugrs,x)) for x in tweets[0:10]]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(counts)
```

This is the best we can do Here, Still the number are huge for each tweet we have an exponential amount of combinations to loop . So It is going to take some time.

**Output for 10 Tweets and all the combinations i.e tweets[0:10]**

```
{'jypetwic+ All Seeds': 2, 'twiceth+ All Seeds': 2, '5th+ All Seeds': 2, 'mini+ All Seeds': 2, 'albumltwhat+ All Seeds': 2, 'lovegtreleas+ All Seeds': 2, 'onlinemelon+ All Seeds': 2, 'twice+ All Seeds': 2, '트와이스+ All Seeds': 2, 'whatislov+ All Seeds': 2, 'u+ All Seeds': 16, 'voidtopaz+ All Seeds': 4, 'fandom+ All Seeds': 4, 'lolchoni+ All Seeds': 4, 'm+ All Seeds': 26, 'sinhuigang+ All Seeds': 2, 'rocket+ All Seeds': 2, 'confid+ All Seeds': 2, 'gayfal+ All Seeds': 2, 'distinguish+ All Seeds': 2, 'gaymi+ All Seeds': 2, 'gay+ All Seeds': 2, 'and+ All Seeds': 11, 're+ All Seeds': 7, 'morwennajh+ All Seeds': 3, 'imagin+ All Seeds': 3, 'painthi+ All Seeds': 3, 'darl+ All Seeds': 3, 'boy+ All Seeds': 6, 'inbut+ All Seeds': 3, 'need+ All Seeds': 3, 'chanc+ All Seeds': 3, 'liveco+ All Seeds': 3, 'singet+ All Seeds': 3, 'get+ All Seeds': 7, 'de+ All Seeds': 9, 'ed+ All Seeds': 3, 'akoposimarcelo+ All Seeds': 1, 'dontdont+ All Seeds': 1, 'deservem+ All Seeds': 1, 'im+ All Seeds': 7, 'live+ All Seeds': 3, 'ke+ All Seeds': 7, 'but+ All Seeds': 3, 'ur+ All Seeds': 10, 'htapmenami+ All Seeds': 5, 'alway+ All Seeds': 5, 'saturday+ All Seeds': 4, 'invit+ All Seeds': 4, 'friend+ All Seeds': 4, 'teach+ All Seeds': 4, 'magicyou+ All Seeds': 4, 'llanowar+ All Seeds': 4, 'elv+ All Seeds': 4, 'promo+ All Seeds': 4, 'll+ All Seeds': 4, 'or+ All Seeds': 5, 'y+ All Seeds': 21, 'p+ All Seeds': 24, 'imag+ All Seeds': 3, 'badrepseokjin+ All Seeds': 2, 'loop+ All Seeds': 2, 'jin+ All Seeds': 2, 'say+ All Seeds': 2, 'korean+ All Seeds': 2, 'english+ All Seeds': 2, 'vid+ All Seeds': 2, 'cr+ All Seeds': 2, 'eundaromi+ All Seeds': 2, 'r+ All Seeds': 26, 'abl+ All Seeds': 5, 'harder+ All Seeds': 5, 'end+ All Seeds': 4, 'sat+ All Seeds': 4, 'h+ All Seeds': 22, 'id+ All Seeds': 8, 'ab+ All Seeds': 5, 'yo+ All Seeds': 7, 'dr+ All Seeds': 2, 'gu+ All Seeds': 5, 'oc+ All Seeds': 2, 'con+ All Seeds': 5, 'f+ All Seeds': 13, 'v+ All Seeds': 25, 'ad+ All Seeds': 3, 'sh+ All Seeds': 4, 'ou+ All Seeds': 7, 'ive+ All Seeds': 3, 'don+ All Seeds': 1, 'n+ All Seeds': 27, 'rock+ All Seeds': 2, 'bu+ All Seeds': 5, 'neadawn808+ All Seeds': 1, 'soo+ All Seeds': 1, 'paint+ All Seeds': 3, 'sin+ All Seeds': 5, 'releas+ All Seeds': 2, 'twic+ All Seeds': 2, 'deserv+ All Seeds': 1, 'sa+ All Seeds': 6, 'l+ All Seeds': 27, 'way+ All Seeds': 5, 'album+ All Seeds': 2, 'melon+ All Seeds': 2, 'k+ All Seeds': 13, 'j+ All Seeds': 11, 've+ All Seeds': 21, 'gucciboytaeba+ All Seeds': 3, 'pass+ All Seeds': 3, 'second+ All Seeds': 3, 'bc+ All Seeds': 3, 'your+ All Seeds': 3, 'th+ All Seeds': 5, 'd+ All Seeds': 25, 'ig+ All Seeds': 2, 'life+ All Seeds': 3, 'go+ All Seeds': 3, 'stress+ All Seeds': 3, 'time+ All Seeds': 3, 'rn+ All Seeds': 3, 'nb+ All Seeds': 3, 'pa+ All Seeds': 10, 'eu+ All Seeds': 2, 'jh+ All Seeds': 3, 'vi+ All Seeds': 6, 'en+ All Seeds': 14, 'ok+ All Seeds': 7, 'b+ All Seeds': 15, 'c+ All Seeds': 21, 'magic+ All Seeds': 4, 'dese+ All Seeds': 1, 'hu+ All Seeds': 2, 'g+ All Seeds': 16, 'op+ All Seeds': 7, 'w+ All Seeds': 15, 'co+ All Seeds': 12, 'ar+ All Seeds': 15, 'fr+ All Seeds': 4, 'ma+ All Seeds': 8, 'e+ All Seeds': 27, 'o+ All Seeds': 27, 'fa+ All Seeds': 6, 'int+ All Seeds': 3, 'ea+ All Seeds': 9, 'bo+ All Seeds': 6, 'ang+ All Seeds': 2, 'di+ All Seeds': 2, 'bro+ All Seeds': 5, 'kor+ All Seeds': 2, 'la+ All Seeds': 4, 'bum+ All Seeds': 2, 'ti+ All Seeds': 7, 'lov+ All Seeds': 18, 'se+ All Seeds': 6, 'dis+ All Seeds': 2, 'ng+ All Seeds': 7, 'lo+ All Seeds': 18, 'und+ All Seeds': 2, 'aint+ All Seeds': 3, 'kore+ All Seeds': 2, 'rom+ All Seeds': 6, 'li+ All Seeds': 10, 'aro+ All Seeds': 2, 'korea+ All Seeds': 2, 'el+ All Seeds': 7, 'ko+ All Seeds': 3, 'al+ All Seeds': 13, 'pro+ All Seeds': 4, 'na+ All Seeds': 8, 'un+ All Seeds': 2, 'lan+ All Seeds': 4, '8+ All Seeds': 1, 'rea+ All Seeds': 2, 'serv+ All Seeds': 1, 'mor+ All Seeds': 3, 'ain+ All Seeds': 3, 'prom+ All Seeds': 4, 'men+ All Seeds': 5, 'tu+ All Seeds': 4, 'ov+ All Seeds': 18, 'mo+ All Seeds': 7, 'pm+ All Seeds': 5, 'mag+ All Seeds': 7, 'sing+ All Seeds': 3, 'gang+ All Seeds': 2, 'ht+ All Seeds': 5, 'ch+ All Seeds': 13, 'te+ All Seeds': 4, 'ting+ All Seeds': 2, 'jyp+ All Seeds': 2, 'thi+ All Seeds': 3, 'ep+ All Seeds': 2, 'anc+ All Seeds': 3, 'st+ All Seeds': 5, 'rd+ All Seeds': 12, 'wha+ All Seeds': 2, 'han+ All Seeds': 3, 'br+ All Seeds': 5, 'wa+ All Seeds': 9, 'in+ All Seeds': 13, 'seokjin+ All Seeds': 2, 'gi+ All Seeds': 7, 'fi+ All Seeds': 2, 'ay+ All Seeds': 13, 'mi+ All Seeds': 11, 'tin+ All Seeds': 2, 'mu+ All Seeds': 3, 'da+ All Seeds': 10, 'cha+ All Seeds': 5, 'ri+ All Seeds': 4, 'oy+ All Seeds': 10, 'mar+ All Seeds': 1, 'nda+ All Seeds': 2, 'ngl+ All Seeds': 2, 'rep+ All Seeds': 2, 'ho+ All Seeds': 4, 'ima+ All Seeds': 4, 'seo+ All Seeds': 2, 'ne+ All Seeds': 6, 'res+ All Seeds': 3, 'lea+ All Seeds': 2, 'turd+ All Seeds': 4, 'et+ All Seeds': 11, 'fe+ All Seeds': 3, 'tim+ All Seeds': 3, '5+ All Seeds': 2, 'fri+ All Seeds': 4, 'line+ All Seeds': 2, 'gt+ All Seeds': 2, 'ro+ All Seeds': 13, 'liv+ All Seeds': 3, 'si+ All Seeds': 6, 'ba+ All Seeds': 5, 'wh+ All Seeds': 2, 'jype+ All Seeds': 2, 'dom+ All Seeds': 4, 'chao+ All Seeds': 2, 'nd+ All Seeds': 13, 'ji+ All Seeds': 2, 'whati+ All Seeds': 2, 'ac+ All Seeds': 4, 'eth+ All Seeds': 2, 'aj+ All Seeds': 3, 'deser+ All Seeds': 1, 'ai+ All Seeds': 3, 'wi+ All Seeds': 2, 'em+ All Seeds': 3, 'cc+ All Seeds': 3, 'ag+ All Seeds': 7, 'what+ All Seeds': 2, 'om+ All Seeds': 10, 'onlin+ All Seeds': 2, 'eco+ All Seeds': 6, 'ove+ All Seeds': 18, 'lon+ All Seeds': 2, 'ot+ All Seeds': 2, 'ol+ All Seeds': 8, 'le+ All Seeds': 2, 'az+ All Seeds': 4, 'pet+ All Seeds': 2, 'ie+ All Seeds': 4, 'ae+ All Seeds': 3, 'dre+ All Seeds': 2, 'chan+ All Seeds': 3, 'po+ All Seeds': 1, 'min+ All Seeds': 2, 'gin+ All Seeds': 3, 'eng+ All Seeds': 2, 'ine+ All Seeds': 2, 'mur+ All Seeds': 3, 'ak+ All Seeds': 1, 'aw+ All Seeds': 1, 'tap+ All Seeds': 5, 'ci+ All Seeds': 3, 'nee+ All Seeds': 3, 'onl+ All Seeds': 2, 'lt+ All Seeds': 2, 'ce+ All Seeds': 3, 'um+ All Seeds': 2, 'ako+ All Seeds': 1, 'ap+ All Seeds': 5, '0+ All Seeds': 1, 'arc+ All Seeds': 1, 'tr+ All Seeds': 5, 'bl+ All Seeds': 5, 'har+ All Seeds': 5, 'rel+ All Seeds': 2, 'ice+ All Seeds': 2, 'tae+ All Seeds': 3, 'gucci+ All Seeds': 3, 'ni+ All Seeds': 6, 'ta+ All Seeds': 8, 'twi+ All Seeds': 2, 'fu+ All Seeds': 3, 'pe+ All Seeds': 2, 'hati+ All Seeds': 2, 'tw+ All Seeds': 2, 'pos+ All Seeds': 1, 'ami+ All Seeds': 5, 'vo+ All Seeds': 4, 'lif+ All Seeds': 3, 'sim+ All Seeds': 1, 'cond+ All Seeds': 3, 'yt+ All Seeds': 3, 'void+ All Seeds': 4, 'relea+ All Seeds': 2, 'whatislo+ All Seeds': 2, 'dawn+ All Seeds': 1, 'sec+ All Seeds': 3, 'ml+ All Seeds': 2, 'eas+ All Seeds': 2, '80+ All Seeds': 1, 'nam+ All Seeds': 5, 'econ+ All Seeds': 3, 'ada+ All Seeds': 1, 'ont+ All Seeds': 1, 'posi+ All Seeds': 1, 'ib+ All Seeds': 3, 'lb+ All Seeds': 2, 'seco+ All Seeds': 3, 'veg+ All Seeds': 2, 'isl+ All Seeds': 2, 'hat+ All Seeds': 2}
```

Comment: it's exactly like what I want to do! but can I ask you one more thing? how to separate them between category? so for example you + all seeds are appear in happy category 3 times an in sad category 2 times. is it possible to do that?

Comment: HI @toheedNiaz is there any way to make the script running faster? I tried using 1000 words as candidates, 1000 words as seeds and 1000 words as tweets and it takes way too long to get the result. do you have any idea how to make it run faster?

Comment: let me see what i can do for you

Comment: wow! thank you so much @toheedNiaz sorry for asking you to help me with this one.

Comment: hi @toheedNiaz have you come up with the solution?

Comment: Bit busy right now will update the answer at my earliest convince

Comment: ah okay. so sorry for bothering you @toheedNiaz :)

Comment: feel free to help me once you're done with all your tasks. :)

Comment: can you try the above code? increase pool to run it in more threads from 10 to more value if you think it is slow

Comment: it takes 30minutes to process 1000 candidates, 5 hours to process 10000 candidates. @toheedNiaz. it's a lot faster somehow but still it's really time consuming.

Comment: Can u share sample set f candidates and provide the link here

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uq52o23ulz5vyy0/candidates%2C%20seeds%2C%20tweets.rar?dl=0 here's the candidates, seeds and tweets that I use.

Comment: have you come up with solution to help me?

Comment: thanks for the updated solution. it works better now. I just only have one problem. the findMatch function only return the candidates that appear together with the seeds in the tweets. the candidates that doesn't appear together with the seeds in the tweets don't get put inside the dictionary. i want to put them as well with value 0. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

toheedNiaz already answered you and it's why I will not redo what he did. but, if you also want to know number of occurences of a pair, you can also do that

```
candidates = ["you", "the", "best", "love", "fun", "feeling", "emotionally"]
seeds = ["happy", "love", "enjoy", "fun", "grace", "sad", "guilty"]
tweets = ["you look so happy", "I am in love with you", "hey you do the best at having fun okay", "i am emotionally sad right now", "feeling guilty"]

    dic = {}
    for candidate in candidates:
        for seed in seeds:
            dic[(candidate,seed)] = 0

    for tweet in tweets:
        for elem in dic:
            if elem[0] in tweet and elem[1] in tweet:
                dic[elem] += 1

    print dic
```

ouput:

```
('the', 'fun'): 1, ('emotionally', 'fun'): 0, ('the', 'grace'): 0, ('love', 'fun'): 0, ('feeling', 'happy'): 0, ('best', 'fun'): 1, ('best', 'sad'): 0, ('you', 'enjoy'): 0, ('love', 'sad'): 0, ('fun', 'love'): 0, ('the', 'happy'): 0, ('best', 'happy'): 0, ('you', 'love'): 1, ('emotionally', 'sad'): 1, ('feeling', 'sad'): 0, ('love', 'happy'): 0, ('fun', 'enjoy'): 0, ('feeling', 'enjoy'): 0, ('the', 'guilty'): 0}
```

Now it's easier to apply treatments.

**EDIT:**

Not super optimized, but it should be better, and it's categorized :

```
candidates = ["you", "the", "best", "love", "fun", "feeling", "emotionally"]
seeds = ["happy", "love", "enjoy", "fun", "grace", "sad", "guilty"]
tweets = ["you look so happy", "I am in love with you", "hey you do the best at having fun okay",
          "i am emotionally sad right now", "feeling guilty"]
dico = {}
for tweet in tweets:
    seeds_list = []
    candidates_list = []
    for word in tweet.split(' '):
        if word in seeds:
            seeds_list.append(word)
        if word in candidates:
            candidates_list.append(word)

    for seed in seeds_list:
        if seed not in dico:
            dico[seed] = len(candidates_list)
        else:
            dico[seed] += len(candidates_list)
```

output:

```
{'sad': 1, 'happy': 1, 'fun': 4, 'guilty': 1, 'love': 2}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. what I mean is i wanna try to separate the result by category. take a look at words in variable seeds. if you look at them, the words are divided into two kind of words. happy category word ones and sad category word ones. if it's possible I wanna know how many times a word from candidate appear in strings and divide them by categories. can you understand what I mean?

Comment: ('you', 'happy'): 1, ('you', 'love'): 1, ('you', 'enjoy'): 0, ('you', 'fun'): 1, ('you', 'grace'): 0, ('you', 'sad'): 0, ('you', 'guilty'): 0 from this result you can tell that word "you" got score 3 when paired with happy word and loop them over the sentences and got score 0 when paired with sad word and loop them over the sentences. I want to be able to get the score based on each emotion category if it's possible. :)

Comment: HI @FlorentY is there any way to make the script running faster? I tried using 1000 words as candidates, 1000 words as seeds and 1000 words as tweets and it takes way too long to get the result. do you have any idea how to make it run faster?